Flutter Web Dashboard - Main Widget not resetting after logout and log back in
I have a web dashboard I made in Flutter. This is my first time making a Flutter app, but I have previous experience with native mobile apps.
I have an issue where I log in as User A, then logout and then log in as User B, and it still shows the previous data from User A. It does not refresh and reload the data for the new user.
I am using BLOCs to manage state and go_router to manage navigation.
For the web dashboard, I am using a StatefulNavigationShell which is part of go_router. I basically have a left "Drawer menu" with some menu (Home, User, Settings etc) and when I click them, the main body of the dashboard will show the corresponding widget. Standard dashboard. However, it seems these are being cached and the BLOC initial state is not being called to make the API requests to get the latest data.
I want to be able to clear this, or tear down my whole app when I logout and redirect to the login screen, but not sure how to do this.
Here is my drawer:
class ScaffoldWithNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  const ScaffoldWithNavigation({super.key, required this.navigationShell});

  @override
  State<ScaffoldWithNavigation> createState() => _ScaffoldWithNavigationState();
}

class _ScaffoldWithNavigationState extends State<ScaffoldWithNavigation> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _ScaffoldWithNavigationRail(widget.navigationShell);
  }
}

class _ScaffoldWithNavigationRail extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ScaffoldWithNavigationRail(this.navigationShell);

  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final colorScheme = theme.colorScheme;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: NavigationAppBar(
        logoutCallback: () => {context.read<DashboardBloc>().add(DashboardLogout())},
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: _NavigationRail(navigationShell: navigationShell, expand: ResponsiveBreakpoints.of(context).largerThan('EXPAND_SIDE_PANEL')),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Icon(Icons.dashboard), //ThemeModeButton.icon(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          VerticalDivider(
            thickness: 1,
            width: 1,
            color: colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.2),
          ),
          Expanded(child: navigationShell),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _NavigationRail extends StatelessWidget {
  const _NavigationRail({required this.navigationShell, required this.expand});

  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;
  final bool expand;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return NavigationRail(
      extended: expand,
      selectedIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
      unselectedLabelTextStyle: theme.textTheme.bodyMedium,
      selectedLabelTextStyle: theme.textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      onDestinationSelected: (index) {
        navigationShell.goBranch(
          index,
          initialLocation: index == navigationShell.currentIndex,
        );
      },
      destinations: _buildDestinations(),
    );
  }
}

Then I have, for example, a Users page which shows a list of users in that logged in users group, so if i change to a new user, it shows the users from the previous group. Here is what my users widget looks like:
class UsersPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const UsersPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<UsersPage> createState() => _UsersPageState();
}

class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<UserBloc, UserState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is UsersLoaded) {
          setState(() {
            users = state.users;
            usersLoading = false;
          });
        } else if (state is UsersLoading) {
          setState(() {
            usersLoading = true;
          });
        }
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is UserInitialState) {
          context.read<UserBloc>().add(FetchUsersEvent());
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (state is UsersLoading) {
          usersLoading = true;
        } 
        
        return _buildUserListList(context);
      }),
    );
  }

When I click the logout button, it calls my DashboardBloc which clears some local data and emits a LogoutSuccess state, which I catch and use go_router to navigate to the login page, like so: context.go(Paths.loginScreen);
So really, what I want to know is how to tear down or reset all the BLOCs in my app. I have 1 for each screen (Login, Dashboard, and Dashboard subscreens). On first login, I can see that the InitialStates are being called, but on 2nd login, these states aren't triggered, so it's like the BLOC is created the first time and reused.
Also, I have another screen that I didn't mention. It uses a Stepper and is like a first time wizard when the user registers. When I finish this Stepper flow, there's a button at the end that says "Enter Dashboard". When I click this, I navigate to the main dashboard and I get errors saying the widget is unmounted. If I navigate from Login it works, but when I navigate from this screen, I get the error. Not sure if it's related.
Thank you for any help.
